# how can avoid horizontal scrolling?

Tags: css, html, scroll, web

My website scrolls left and right and i can't find why? can anyone help me? this is the link
http://snf-36202.vm.okeanos.grnet.gr/eud/index2.php

Comment: Use the dev tools to find elements wider than the viewport width. You can emulate mobile devices with Chrome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because div's are by default 100% width.
If you change them to display:inline-block it'll be fine because they'll have the width of their content then.

Comment: is it wrong if i change the width in the body element?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: body{
background-size:1200px 1200px;
background-image:url(1a.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat

background-position:center; 
width:500px;
}

Comment: Never change body width. If you want to make something "hold" the content in the center, create a div, and give that a width.

Comment: if i write div{ display:inline-block;} buttons spread all over the screen and when i create the div and fix the width it seems right on my laptop ,but if i open it on my mobile my background seems half :/

Comment: It seems like you fixed it, but you shouldn't do it on all div's only those 4 buttons.
I suggest you add a second class like, .button and apply it to that.
But you seem to have fixed it already.